# Eclipse exports an empty plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, export, knime

I wrote a plugin for eclipse ( [knime](http://tech.knime.org/node/10043) ). But the jar generated by eclipse doesn't contain any class:

```
jar tvf plugins/fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes_1.0.0.jar
     0 Thu May 19 08:45:26 CEST 2011 META-INF/
  2543 Thu May 19 08:45:24 CEST 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  7941 Thu May 19 08:45:24 CEST 2011 plugin.xml
```

here is the content of my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Node extension for KNIME Workbench
Bundle-SymbolicName: fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: Pierre
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.knime.workbench.core,
 org.knime.workbench.repository,
 org.knime.base
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.corelib.bio,
 fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.corelib.knime,
 fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.corelib.util,
 fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes.bam.view,
 fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes.sql.query;
  uses:="org.knime.core.node,
   org.eclipse.core.runtime,
   org.osgi.framework,
   org.knime.core.data,
   org.knime.core.node.defaultnodesettings,
   fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.corelib.knime",
 fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes.unix.echo;
 (... other packages here ...)
  uses:="fr.inserm.umr915.knime4ngs.nodes,
   org.knime.core.node,
   org.eclipse.core.runtime,
   org.osgi.framework,
   org.knime.core.node.defaultnodesettings"
```

ay help ?
Thanks

**EDIT**:
and here is my build.properties:

```
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to add information, a common *build.properties* file for a plugin (with a standard *project/src* directory has 3 properties defined:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           .,\
           icons/
```

`source..` and `output..` defined the source and output location for `.`.  the `.,\` in `bin.includes` tells eclipse to include the `.` library when exporting.